# Is there any performance-wise difference between two ways of sql insert statement?

Tags: mysql

```
1.insert into demotable1(list_of_all_columns) select * from demotable2 where some_condition;
2.insert into demotable1 select * from demotable2 where some_condition;
```

note: Table structure of demotable1 and demotable2 are same.

Which one of the above query statement is optimal?

Comment: What have you tried so far? What do you expect?

Comment: You forgot a third option: `insert into demotable1(list_of_all_columns) select list_of_all_columns from demotable2 where some_condition;`

Comment: *Which one of the above query statement is optimal?* None. List all columns explicitly in all places like @Solarflare claims.

Comment: test both versions on lots of data and you will have your answer. I suspect that the results would only be marginally different from each other.

Comment: @Solarflare ,Akina ,Shadow I want to know which query will take relatively less time among two. (These are only two ways to run my query. I don't want to consider third option.)

Comment: As an estimate, the execution time will differ by the time required to send the longer text to the server. This will depend on your connection speed.

Answer (score 1):

"Optimal" -- They are the same.

MySQL will expand `*` into a list of columns as part of the parsing of the query.  If you have a list of columns, it will verify that they are valid.  So, no significant difference in performance.  In general, performance of a query is dominated by fetching rows, *not* the details of what goes on inside the row.

"Desirable" --

On the other hand, `*` should not be used in most situations.  What if you later added or deleted a column?  Suddenly most queries with `*` in them would break.  The main exception:  You are simply dumping the data to see what is in the table.

Hence, option 3 is the only desirable version; it is unfortunate that it is not available.